# Unable to include imploded variable into array to run query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm unsure if my title aptly named. Nevertheless, here's my problem.Below query iterates through the array and returns all 6 records (3 records for each id).

But when I replace

```
$key = array(1,2)  with
$a=$data['sub'];

foreach($a as $v=>$k) 
  {

    $key0[]=$v;

  }
 $key2=implode(',',$key0);
```

it only returns result for 1 id. I wonder why, in fact echo `$key2` is equal to `1,2`.

```
$postcode=$data['postcode'];
$rate=$data['slider1'];
**$key = array(1,2);**
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($key), '?'));

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.subid IN (".$in.") AND posts.pricing=?  AND posts.Poscode=? ORDER BY posts.Poscode DESC LIMIT 60");
$result = array_merge($key, array($rate,$postcode));
$statement->execute($result);
$json = array();
while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
    array_push($json, array("name" => $row['Name'], "id" => $row['PostUUID'],"rate" => $row['pricing'],"postcode" => $row['Poscode'],"reputation" => $row['Reputation'],"plus" => $row['ReviewPlus'],"neg" => $row['ReviewNeg'],"weekM" => $row['week_morning'],"weekA" => $row['week_afternoon'],"weekE" => $row['week_evening'],"endM" => $row['weekend_morning'],"endA" => $row['weekend_afternoon'],"endE" => $row['weekend_evening']));
}
```

Comment: $key0 is array ? where did you define it ?

Comment: @Noman, I define it above like $key0=array();

Comment: you define `$key = array(1,2)` not `$key0`

Comment: @Noman, what is the exact error? I don't understand why if I hardcode an array it can work but when replaced with variable it doesn't ? How do I define the $key0 then? I've been cracking my head for hours now, can you give me the exact code please? Thank you

Comment: add `$key0 = array();` before this line `$key = array(1,2)`

Comment: @Noman, I tried it, doesn't help.. I think, pdo identifies this $array($key2); as a string, how to make it understand that it's not?